# Why my Flutter app is not building while executing?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build

I have been trying to build a flutter app. But while exporting/building it an error came. The error message while building:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
C:\dev\bmi\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Package name 'BMI' at position AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-18 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Package name 'BMI' at position AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-18 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

`andriodmainifest.xml:`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="BMI">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Share your android manifest file here

Comment: ```@Suganya``` I have added the file in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is on your package name given in manifest file.
You can add package name as com.bmi or so on.
Kindly refer below added manifest file from my project.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bmi">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.network-policy"
            android:resource="@xml/network_security_config" />
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```